# How do you turn off swagger-ui in production

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have swagger plugged in to my spring boot application.  Spring boot allows you to have property files for each environment that you have.  Is there a way to disable swagger for a production environment?

Answer (score 32):

Put your swagger configuration into separate configuration class and annotate it with `@Profile` annotation -> so that it will be scanned into Spring context only in certain profiles.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("dev")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    // your swagger configuration
}
```

You can than define profile your Spring Boot app is operating in via command line: `--spring.profiles.active=dev` or via config file: `spring.profiles.active=dev`.

[Read this section of Spring Boot docs for more info about `@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: we've done this and it appears that the extension -> swagger-ui.html still appears even though the guts of the api's aren't showing.  Is there a way to make it so the swagger-ui.html doesn't even get produced?

Comment: @user301693 If you're using Maven you can load the swagger dependencies within a specific Maven profile, that should do the trick I guess.

Comment: @g00glen00b, and have different artifacts for PROD than for other environments? I guess QA and OPS guys wouldn't be very happy with that.

Comment: /swagger-ui.html still available but there is no methods. Is there way to forbid URL ?

Comment: do not work, the HTML page is display (not with REST API but display anyway)

Comment: Correct, this approach turns off only back-end. Please refer to SO question provided by @gstackoverflow

Comment: I know it's an old question, but we use @Profile("!prod") to avoid specifying tons of other profiles explicitly. Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: not working with swagger 3

Answer (score 28):

If you are working on multiple environments then you can also use **@Profile** as array

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"dev","qa"})
public class SwaggerConfig {
   // your swagger configuration
}
```

Comment: Yes it is valid I also want to know why down vote... thanks Jin Kwon

Comment: It is not from me the downvote but this will disable json endpoints only probably and not webjar ui page?

Answer (score 10):

with swagger 3.0.0 version you can add `springfox.documentation.enabled=false` in corresponding environment profile `application.properties` file. For example, I have added this to `application-prod.properties` to disable in production (while running the app you must specify the profile using VM args like `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this simple answer. It works!

Comment: In case you're using SpringDoc, it has a similar alternative:
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false

Comment: since v1.1.16 property was changed: `springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false`

Answer (score 5):

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("swagger")
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${info.build.version}")
    private String buildVersion;

    @Bean
    public Docket documentation() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(regex("/rest/.*"))
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(metadata());
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API documentation of our App")
                .description("Use this documentation as a reference how to interact with app's API")
                .version(buildVersion)
                .contact(new Contact("Dev-Team", "https://dev-website", "dev@mailbox"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Wherever I need Swagger, I add the profile `swagger` to the environment variable     `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`

Comment: This essentially duplicates [the other, much older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796782/1240557) (i.e. "use profile")

Comment: /swagger-ui.html still available but there is no methods. Is there way to forbid URL ?

Comment: I think this is more neater way of enabling swagger on demand, instead of disabling for some profiles.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but if you are using SpringDoc v1.2.12+:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

From:
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/191#issuecomment-558809236

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers configuring Spring using a *profile*, consider having rules on your reverse HTTP proxy to block access to the Swagger end points from outside the LAN. That would give you some defence in depth against attacks on the Swagger end points.

Answer (score 0):

For those that use code gen (which generates Swagger2SpringBoot):

1. Write your own Swagger2SpringBoot (with the @Profile bit) and locate it in the same package path as the autogenerated one.
2. Edit swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to place generated into src/main/java (which will overwrite your own one in point 1.
3. Edit .swagger-codegen-ignore to not overwrite your Swagger2SpringBoot
4. Note other stuff will also be overwritten eg. pom.xml and application.properties. Just add them to .swagger-codegen-ignore too.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

1. have configuration for env

   @Configuration

   @EnableSwagger2

   @Profile("devone")
2. application.yaml

   ```
   profiles: 

   active:

    ${MY_ENV:devone}
   ```

MY_ENV you will read from file, like .env

.env file content:
MY_ENV=prod

In the production keep other .env file only for production credentials.

Answer (score -1):

**spring.profiles.active=production with @Profile("!production")** worked for me to turn off swagger in prod.

Ex :-

```
@Profile("!production")
@Component
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
       //TODO
}
```