# Turn off open API specification in production environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

I saw a similar answer for `Swagger 2.x` here - [How do you turn off swagger-ui in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794571/how-do-you-turn-off-swagger-ui-in-production) so I was wondering if there is something similar I could do for open API as well? I tried something like :

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!prod")
public class OpenAPIConfig 
{
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

May be you can set the below property in prod yaml,

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 3):

Following properties can be used based on active profile

```
# To disable UI
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false

# To disable API
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: false
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
```